# ¿Cuál es la documentación de SAPUI5?

Tags: css, css3

Estoy usando el framework de SAP para front-end, pero no encuentro una documentación o una lista en donde me especifiquen las clases predefinidas de CSS que tiene este framework. Quisiera saber cuáles son los enlaces correspondientes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dentro de su propia documentación, tienes una **[lista](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91a4946b0dcf4356aaaedc4e502864f4.html)** con todas sus clases de CSS disponibles.

Las clases de CSS disponibles son:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]